# Only get Cors Header error when accessing media files, rest of the app works fine (DRF, pythonanywhere, React)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cors, pythonanywhere, django-cors-headers

This is happening on both chrome and firefox. I have a react app that communicates fine with my django rest framework backend until I try to access an uploaded mp3 media file.  I then get:

" has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

If I click on the error media link within chrome console it will take me to the uploaded mp3 and it will play fine.

My app is deployed on Pythonanywhere. My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tagging',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'STATIC')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'MEDIA')

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('tagging.urls')),
    path('api/api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have static & media files setup within the pythonanywhere web app:

URL:/STATIC/ Directory: /home/username/project/STATIC

URL:/MEDIA/ Directory: /home/username/project/MEDIA

not sure why this is occurring, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: how is your app served? (reverse proxy?, nginx? apache?)

Comment: nginx I believe.  I realised it has something to do with how I am calling the media through wavesurferjs.  Still can;t figure out how to fix it though

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to nginx config files, look into your server configuration. If there is a location for `media`, you should add manually the required header.

The issue is linked to the fact that media files are served by nginx, and not your app, so django corsheaders has no effect on these resources:

```
server {
        ...

        location /media/ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            root /path/to/your/project/root;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but apparently pythonanywhere does not let you configure nginx config files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve static files with CORS headers, then you will need to serve them from your web app and not use the static files mappings.

Comment: How can I configure this with Django Rest Framework on PythonAnywhere? When I tried doing it that way with the same url pattern in my OP, I get 404.  All I could find on python anywhere forums about media URLs is people saying to map the files like static